# Need help figuring out which youtube html tag to get in order to load a video in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a script that loads the first youtube video that appears after entering a search query using `requests` and `bs4.BeautifulSoup`. It seems all youtube videos have an `a`tag with an id of `#video-title`. Therefore I would think the simplest solution is to use `soup.findAll("#video-title")` But the list of tags always come up empty. I'm not sure which tags to select in order to `href` that will ultimately load the video.

Comment: Are you sure content isn't dynamically loaded? Also share example url

Comment: Videos most likely are loaded dynamically but I'm not sure how that affects whether or not you can parse it or not. An example url would simply be a search page after a query is entered such as [link](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Happy+Together) @QHarr

Answer (score 0):

```py
video = soup.findAll('a',attrs={'class':'yt-uix-tile-link'})
```

[For more information check this article](https://allofyourbases.com/2017/10/08/web-scraping-youtube-in-python/)

Comment: # is an id selector

Comment: "video-title" is an id. Tried `soup.findAll('a',attrs={'id':'video-title'})` as well, returned an empty list.

Comment: Please explain why this should work. This increases the value of your answer for future visitors of our knwoledge base.